# Geoplugin SSL - Country undefined error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable my live chat from displaying by blocking countries India and Pakistan.

I used the tool from http://www.geoplugin.com and it worked great. However - I was using the typical http javascript. I just bought the `SSL` version from them so that there wouldn't be a conflict with my current website which uses `HTTPS` and the new javascript.

However - now that I use it - I get the error message

> Uncaught ReferenceError: geoplugin_countryCode is not defined

My website is https://www.blueskychat.com

The code is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://ssl.geoplugin.net/json.gp?k=..." type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var countryCode = geoplugin_countryCode();
    if (countryCode != 'IN' && countryCode != 'PK') {
        window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
        window.__lc.license = 8653536;
        window.__lc.chat_between_groups = false;
        window.__lc.ga_version = "ga";
        (function() {
            var lc = document.createElement('script');
            lc.type = 'text/javascript';
            lc.async = true;
            lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
        })();
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas as to what is the problem and how to resolve?

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you use this plugin? Where is the code that uses it?

Comment: What do you mean? It is a geolocation plugin see above. The other script runs perfectly normal (the live chat) but I only want it to load if you are not in in India or Pakistan

Comment: I mean, where is the code that _loads_ this plugin? Like `<script src="..."></script>`? WARNING! Remove `k=...` from `src` before posting it here.

Comment: Is it bad security to add the K =  here in stack? I thought it would be public if you view the source code of the website?

Comment: Not a "bad security" per se, just it's one thing to use it on your site and another thing is to post it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading `json` response, but attempting to use `javascript` method.

Just replace `json.gp` with `javascript.gp` in your `src` attribute of loading script and it will work.